# Declarations of 2 modules in Ionic 4

Tags: declaration, ionic4

I have 2 pages, with 2 modules, and try to use the same pipe, so I have declarate the same pipe in each page.

listview.module.ts

```
import { DateTimePipe } from '../pipes/dateTime.pipe';

declarations: [ListviewPage, DateTimePipe,]
```

profile.module.ts

```
import { DateTimePipe } from '../pipes/dateTime.pipe';

declarations: [ProfilePage, DateTimePipe]
```

and for this, I get this problem:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type DateTimePipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ListviewPageModule and ProfilePageModule! Please consider moving DateTimePipe to a higher module that imports ListviewPageModule and ProfilePageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DateTimePipe then import that NgModule in ListviewPageModule and ProfilePageModule.
>   Error: Type DateTimePipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ListviewPageModule and ProfilePageModule! Please consider moving DateTimePipe to a higher module that imports ListviewPageModule and ProfilePageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DateTimePipe then import that NgModule in ListviewPageModule and ProfilePageModule.

I try to declare it in app.module.ts but don't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a shared module, place your pipe in that module then import the shared module into other places as you require.

SharedModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTimePipe } from '../pipes/dateTime.pipe';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DateTimePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        DateTimePipe
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

listview.module.ts

```
...
imports: [SharedModule]
...
```

profile.module.ts

```
...
imports: [SharedModule]
...
```

Comment: I had to import the CommonModule in Shared.module to work, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTimePipe } from '../pipes/dateTime.pipe';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DateTimePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        DateTimePipe
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

then following @Shannon answer. **IonicModule** required for ionic4 application.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue with using SafeHtmlPipe. Using the answers mention above I can't use it for my innerHTML

Comment: I have sloved the issue. I have to put pipe in providers in sharedPage.